# How to networking in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

Here is my working condition:

1. My laptop @ 192.168.12.85 gw 192.168.1.254
2. Controll plane : bino-k8-master @ 192.168.1.66 gw 192.168.1.247
3. worker node : bino-k8-wnode1 @ 192.168.1.67 gw 192.168.1.247

k8s cluster is build per https://www.hostafrica.ng/blog/kubernetes/kubernetes-ubuntu-20-containerd/

I build simple flask app image per https://faun.pub/run-your-flask-app-on-kubernetes-ff03854db842

Currently, the app is running:

```
ubuntu@bino-k8-master:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
flask-k8s-deployment-59bd54648c-jdgxv   1/1     Running   0          16h   10.244.1.8   bino-k8-wnode1   <none>           <none>
```

also the service:

```
ubuntu@bino-k8-master:~$ kubectl get services -o wide
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
flask-k8s-service   LoadBalancer   10.96.179.198   <pending>     6000:30787/TCP   17h   app=flask-k8s
kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          18h   <none>
```

But I can not access the app or service from control plane ...
curl http://10.244.1.8:5000 and http://10.96.179.198:6000  both failed (no message, just stuck)

But both curl will work if I did it from the worker node.

Kindly please tell me what to do to make the app or service can be acessed from my laptop (192.168.1.85)

Sincerely

Bino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access it from a laptop you need to get the extenal-ip of the load balancer. It is not on screenshot yet. If you want just to test it, you can port forward with correct ports.

```
kubectl port-forward flask-k8s-deployment-59bd54648c-jdgxv 3000:3000
```

and then just call

```
http://localhost:3000
```

If you want to access it from internet, create https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/